# android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED won't fire when SMS comes from an e-mail

Tags: android, email, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver

My `BroadcastReceiver` works just fine when the device receives an SMS from another regular phone, but if the SMS is sent through the carrier's e-mail gateway like "myphonenumber@mycarrier.com", then the message is received on the device normally as an SMS, but the `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` action does not fire and my `BroadcatReceiver` never gets notified. Is there something I'm missing?

```
<receiver android:name=".services.IncomingSmsBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something interesting about how carriers handle e-mails, which in turn was causing wrong behavior in my `if` statements, which in turn caused the problem stated in this question.


Apparently, when cell phone service providers handle e-mails to your phone, they send it through a random short number: like 4043 for example. In your `BroadcastReceiver`, when you get a hold of the `SmsMessage`, you should always use `SmsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress()` and `SmsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody()`. These will give you the e-mail address that sent it and the proper body respectively. Unlike `SmsMessage.getOriginatingAddress()` and `SmsMessage.getMessageBody()` which will give you instead the random number mentioned previously and the body containing the e-mail address mixed up with the actual content.